# Is GIS SE good place for 'map critique' questions?

Tags: discussion

I've been visiting [Map Gallery](http://www.cartotalk.com/index.php?showforum=14) section of [CartoTalk](http://www.cartotalk.com/) forum from time to time.

I found it very useful to post an example of my (amateur) cartographic output and get some feedback and comments on them. And I also learn a lot from other posts.

Do you think GIS SE could serve a similar role where question would be basically a map produced by the user asking for critical comments on design/cartographic aspects of it? Both good and bad sides? What would be an appropriate tag(s) for that?

***UPDATE*** (following @whuber comment): I do not envisage this type of questions to be in the form - 'Hey.. here is my map.. whataya think?' Question would probably have to present some more challenging / unusual type of visualization / cartographic output (I realize the fact that it might be highly subjective issue though). And asks about issues like:

- Are there any particular mistakes that I haven't thought about (choice of colors, fonts, legibility, composition, missing elements in legend, etc.)?
- Is this type of visualization adequate?
- If not what other options would be more appropriate?
- Have I chosen appropriate technique considering my (envisaged) audience?

Comment: To jump-start this discussion, take a look at what [the Photography community says about a similar issue](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2039/).

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the link - I have updated my question to clarify the issue a little bit more.

Answer (score 5):

Why not try it and see how it works out? We should be cognisant as you stated that it is easy to be too broad to be useful (this also makes it difficult to give useful answers as well). I would be more concerned if I thought it would be opening up the floodgates, but I'm skeptical such problematic behavior would occur.

In short, when sufficiently focused I believe they would be fine, and as long as they are infrequent such questions can be evaluated on a case-by-case basis as to whether they are reasonable questions for the community.